# Привязать один StaticResource двум разным контролам

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется 2 UserControl'а, которые имеют определённый ряд кнопок. 
Контент им задаётся изображениями через StaticResource. 
StaticResource представляют из себя xaml-иконку в ResourceDictionary вида:

```
<Path x:Key="AddIcon" 
      Width="24" Height="24" 
      Data="M13,9H18.5L13,3.5V9M6,2H14L20,8V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6C4.89,22 4,21.1 4,20V4C4,2.89 4.89,2 6,2M11,15V12H9V15H6V17H9V20H11V17H14V15H11Z" 
      Fill="Black" />
```

В главном окне подключаются оба UserControl'а, но в зависимости от режима, отображается только одно (другое Collapsed):

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Padding="3">
        <!-- Menu Items -->
    </Menu>
    <!-- User Control -->
    <controls:AnimeControl Visibility="{Binding Mode.AnimeVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <controls:MangaControl Visibility="{Binding Mode.MangaVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <!--/ User Control -->
</DockPanel>
```

Код для отображения кнопок в обоих UserControl'ах одинаковый:

```
<DockPanel Margin="5,3">
    <Button Content="{StaticResource UpdateIcon}" ToolTip="Обновить список" Margin="1,0" />
    <Button Content="{StaticResource InfoIcon}" ToolTip="Подробное инфо о тайтле" Margin="0" />
    <Button Content="{StaticResource AddIcon}" ToolTip="Добавить новый тайтл" Margin="1,0" />
    <Button Content="{StaticResource SearchIcon}" ToolTip="Поиск" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <TextBox Margin="1,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Name="localSearchTextBox" GotFocus="localSearchTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="localSearchTextBox_LostFocus">Поиск...</TextBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Но в конечном итоге у меня только в одном из контролов в кнопках отображаются изображения. Это видно уже даже на превью в студии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Неужели один StaticResource можно использовать только для одного контрола?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема в том, что вы создали 1 экземпляр контрола и пытаетесь добавить его в 2 места, что делать нельзя.

[тут та же проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924151/content-of-a-button-style-appears-only-in-one-button-instance/42924819#42924819). и есть решение.

В вашем случае рекомендую сделать так:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddIcon">
        <Path
            Width="24"
            Height="24"
            Data="M13,9H18.5L13,3.5V9M6,2H14L20,8V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6C4.89,22 4,21.1 4,20V4C4,2.89 4.89,2 6,2M11,15V12H9V15H6V17H9V20H11V17H14V15H11Z"
            Fill="Black" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Использовать ресурс:

```
<Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AddIcon}" ToolTip="Обновить список" Margin="1,0" />
```

Comment: Что значит 1 экземпляр контрола? AnimeControl и MangaControl это два разных usercontrol'а. Просто очень похожи. Или речь про button'ы, но они вовсе неименованы же =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest в ResourceDictionary Вы создали один экземпляр Path с ключом AddIcon. И его пытаетесь использовать в 2 местах визуального дерева. (как контент двух кнопок, по одной на 1 контрол)

Comment: То есть мне нужно добавить x:Shared=false во все кнопки, что имеют общий контент? Или этот аттрибут надо добавить в Path?

Comment: x:Shared добавить в Path. Но лично я рекомендую обернуть Path с DataTemplate и использовать ContentTemplate у Button. [мой же пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42924819/4627031)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как ваш пример применить к Path =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest Обновил ответ.

Comment: Кажется понял. Спасибо, дома попробую)

Comment: @Mr.Modest Работать будет аналогичен, в моем примере главное, это обертка DataTemplate вокруг Path.